# Word for stating "negative influence on other opinions"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the word for influencing others' decisions and opinions in a negative way?

In other words, what is the best choice to fill the blank in the following example:

> To avoid -----, the comments are not visible for the participants until the end of the session.

Comment: The best word that would fit in the blank may actually be _influencing_.

Comment: ***Biasing***, ***skewing***, ***coloring***, ***influencing***, and so on (a thesaurus will help).

Comment: @DanBron, **Biasing** was my first choice, but I'm looking for a better and less heard choice. Searching couldn't help, by the way!

Comment: @Eilia Why didn't searching help? I just googled *bias synonyms*, and immediately got this list of synonyms for the verb sense: *prejudice, influence, color, sway, weight, predispose; distort, skew, slant*. What's wrong with those?

Comment: @Eilia Are you looking specifically for a word that would say "the comments might ----- the decisions of the participants"? where the ----- is a negative influence?

Comment: I think it is better to use "To collect unbiased data/opinion" sounds more idiomatic than using "To avoid..." In what context will you use the sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative" or "in a negative way" in your question? Are only the "negative" comments being hidden until the end? I ask because "positive" comments could be expected to "positively influence" the opinions of subsequent comment makers, no? Does "negatively" here mean "make something be different from what it would have been otherwise" (whether the difference is positive or negative/more for or more against the thing being evaluated)? Is it the notion of "the evil effects of peer pressure" that you're after?

Comment: Interestingly we have [delusion of control](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-delusion%20of%20control) which actually is the other way round of your question as [here](http://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Delusion%20Of%20Control) you are not influencing 'their' mind but  they'll feel they are 'under the influence'.

Answer (score 6):

From [Oxford *living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudice)

> Prejudice
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
> Give rise to prejudice in (someone); make biased:
>
> ‘the statement might prejudice the jury’

More example sentences from OLD

> *‘The smell of antiseptic and the fear of injections prejudiced me against him then, but he was the most important person in our village.’*
>
> *‘There are very many legal things I can think of that would prejudice me against a person more than smoking.’*

Your sentence:

> To avoid **prejudicing** the participants, the comments will not be visible until the end of the session.

Synonyms:
bias, influence, sway, predispose, make biased, make partial, make partisan, colour, poison, jaundice, warp, twist, slant, distort

Answer (score 3):

How about **bias**?

OD:

> [**bias**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bias): a systematic distortion of a statistical result due to a factor not allowed for in its derivation

Your example:

> To avoid **bias**, the comments are not visible for the participants
>   until the end of the session.

Making comments available ahead of time has the potential to distort the views of the participants when what you want is their own personal **unbiased** feedback.

Answer (score 1):

***mental contamination***

> Contamination: The act or process of contaminating; pollution; defilement; taint; also, that which contaminates; The process of making a material or surface unclean or unsuited for its intended purpose, usually by the addition or attachment of undesirable foreign substances.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/contamination)]

Comment: @NVZ, thank you for quietly guiding me in my correctness on citations.  I do need the help, being as excruciatingly new as I am.  Very grateful...

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for ***manipulation*** - (negatively) influencing opinions to serve one's own (often selfish) interests.

> To avoid ***manipulation*** (of individual opinions), the comments are
>   not visible for the participants until the end of the session.

M-W:

> **[manipulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulated)**
>   *verb*
>   **3 :**  to change by artful or unfair means so as to serve one's purpose
>
> The editorial was a blatant attempt to ***manipulate*** public opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I submit that a good choice is not one word but two:

> To avoid inhibiting discussion, the comments are not visible for the
>   participants until the end of the session.

Comment: @DarshanBaral - Curse those dyslexic fingers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***distraction***

[googles definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=distraction%20meaning)

> dis·trac·tion
>   dəˈstrakSH(ə)n/
>
> distraction; plural noun: distractions
>
> 1) a thing that prevents someone from giving full attention to something else.
>
> 2)
>
> "the company found passenger travel a distraction from the main business of moving freight"
>
> synonyms:  diversion, interruption, disturbance, interference, hindrance
>
> "a distraction from the real issues"

To use it in your sentence:

To avoid [distraction], the comments are not visible for the participants until the end of the session.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest there is no such word.

Any of the answers or comments here before might *influence* any opinion but not one word says anything about specifically *negative* influence.

Even '*misguidance*' and '*disinformation*' are simply tools of dishonesty which could be used either way, including to *positively* influence an opinion.

The questions seems a lot like asking whether a gun could *negatively* kill someone, but not *positively*.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to absorb the vibe of what you're trying to say, and here's what I came up with:

***limit participants' thinking***

But you wanted something more on the esoteric side, I think, so here's a fun synonym for *limit*:

***circumscribe participants' thinking***

> *circumscribe* (with object): Restrict (something) within limits:
>   ‘the minister's powers are circumscribed both by tradition and the organization of local government’

[(Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/circumscribe)

Your sentence:

> To avoid **circumscribing** participants' thinking, the comments are not visible for the participants until the end of the session.

This means that reading the comments prematurely would hold people back from thinking deeply about the issues on their own.  *Circumscribe* is also used in geometry (draw a figure around another, touching it at points but not cutting it -- Oxford again).  Exposing the comments prematurely would put a fence around some ideas in the participants' heads.  But you want their thinking to be able to move freely around, without the fence.

Answer (score 0):

*Corruption* is the nice blanket term. But the way that word is used 99% of the time will make that not ideal. *Corrupting* is also an option.

*Vitiation* doesn't really work but it sort of does. Most people probably wont know what it means off hand, though.

*Subvert* isn't ideal either.

Coercion.

In this instance what coercion would be directly saying is that the manner in which the opinions would be changed would be untraditional and not ideal for the victim (which arguably is the case here). It should be noted that typically one is being coerced to do something negative too, and thats why i think its somewhat appropriate for this situation.

I'm going to assume that the main thing thats negative is the changes themselves, not the manner in which the changes are made.

There are many words which refer to negative ways inwhich persuasion can occur. But not many touch on whether or not the changes themselves are good or bad. Seduce sort of works, but not in this setting. I think corrupt may be the best one.

Theres beguile, to influence by trickery, flattery.

Cajole, to persuade by flattery or promises.

Coax, to attempt to influence by gentle persuasion, flattery.

Wheedle, to endeavor to influence (a person) by smooth, flattering, or beguiling words or acts.

I think "influence" may also be a contender. Influence generally refers to (and maybe implies?) negative effects. And i don't think theres much in regards to connotations on the manner in which the influencing occurs.

Brainwash, again, implies that the process is negative too.

Proselytize means to try to get someone over to your side or your way of seeing things. But it implies intent and i think you want to allow for the possibility that the influencing is unintentional (which would definitely be the more professional way of phrasing it).

Answer (score -1):

> To avoid **negativity**, the comments are not visible for the participants until the end of the session.

***Negativity*** — [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/negativity)

> (noun) 1. habitual skepticism and a disagreeable tendency to deny or oppose or resist suggestions or commands

Usage example from [New York Times Jan 6, 2017](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/06/briefing/europe-briefing.html)

> A psychologist asks this question to help overcome negativity.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We are actually looking for longer answers that provide source and context. Comments are restricted to the comments section below the question. If you need assistance in drafting an answer, please consult our [Help page on "Writing a good answer":](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)